# converting string class name to an object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have this trait which i want to use dependency injection

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
 trait ControllerTrait{


public function index($this->model $payroll){

    return $this->model->paginate(20);
   } 
}
```

the controller which uses this trait

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Payroll;

class PayrollController extends Controller
{
   use ControllerTrait;

   public $model = "Payroll";


 }
```

$model now is a string how to convert it to an object in calling index method of the trait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe dynamic type-hinting is possible, nor is it necessary in this instance.

I imagine this is what you're looking for.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

trait ControllerTrait{
    public function index() {
        return ('\App\\'.$this->model)::paginate(20);
    }
}
```

Comment: why can't i use

  return ($this->model)::paginate(20);

   public $model = App\Payroll::class

it gives an error

Comment: Try adding a preceding slash like `public $model = \App\Payroll::class;`.  That works for me along with `($this->model)::paginate(20);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "call_user_func" function which can call function in your model.

```
public $model = "Payroll";
call_user_func($model . "::index");
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use it as a string in php

```
$controllerClassName = 'TODOS\CONTROLLERS\\' . ucfirst($this->_controller) . 'Controller';
```

which is a string and i used it to create instances

```
$controller = new $controllerClassName();
```